# How to mock 'find' method in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, testing, doctrine-orm, mocking

I´m trying to mock the `find` method of the `EntityRepository`,so that the test doesn't look for the data in the database but it doesn´t seem to work. Here's the `setUp` method of the test class

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->client = static::createClient();
    $this->peopleManager = $this->getMockBuilder(PeopleManager::class)
        ->setMethods(['createPerson','peopleUpdate', 'peopleDelete', 'peopleRead'])
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

   $this->repository = $this->getMockBuilder(EntityRepository::class)
       ->disableOriginalConstructor()
       ->getMock();

   $this->em = $this->getMockBuilder(EntityManager::class)
       ->disableOriginalConstructor()
       ->getMock(); 
}
```

This is the method where we call the find function

```
public function updatePersonAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('GeneralBundle:People');
    $person= $repository->find($id);
    if($person)
    {
        $data = $request->request->get('array');
        $createdPeople = array();
        $UpdatedPerson = "";
        foreach($data as $content)
        {
            $prueba = $this->get('people.manager');
            $UpdatedPerson = $prueba->peopleUpdate(
                $person,
                $content['name'],
                $content['surname'],
                $content['secondSurname'],
                $content['nationality'],
                $content['birthday'],
                $content['identityCard'],
                $content['identityCardType']
            );
            array_push($createdPeople, $person);
        }
        $serializedEntity = $this->get('serializer')->serialize($UpdatedPerson, 'json');
        return new Response($serializedEntity);
    } else {
        $serializedEntity = $this->get('serializer')->serialize('Doesn\'t exists any person with this id', 'json');
        return new Response($serializedEntity);
    }
}
```

The debugger shows that the peoplemanager class is mocked but it doesn't mock the entity manager and the repository.

Thank you <3.

Comment: With Mockery it is pretty trivial http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/ give it a try something like `$repo->shouldReceive('find')->once()->andReturn([1,2,3]);`

Comment: Thank you, this is very usefull !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose the class you want to test looks like this:

```
// src/AppBundle/Salary/SalaryCalculator.php
namespace AppBundle\Salary;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class SalaryCalculator
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function calculateTotalSalary($id)
    {
        $employeeRepository = $this->entityManager
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Employee');
        $employee = $employeeRepository->find($id);

        return $employee->getSalary() + $employee->getBonus();
    }
}
```

Since the ObjectManager gets injected into the class through the constructor, it's easy to pass a mock object within a test:

```
// tests/AppBundle/Salary/SalaryCalculatorTest.php
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Salary;

use AppBundle\Entity\Employee;
use AppBundle\Salary\SalaryCalculator;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class SalaryCalculatorTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testCalculateTotalSalary()
    {
        // First, mock the object to be used in the test
        $employee = $this->createMock(Employee::class);
        $employee->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getSalary')
            ->will($this->returnValue(1000));
        $employee->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getBonus')
            ->will($this->returnValue(1100));

        // Now, mock the repository so it returns the mock of the employee
        $employeeRepository = $this
            ->getMockBuilder(EntityRepository::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $employeeRepository->expects($this->once())
            ->method('find')
            ->will($this->returnValue($employee));

        // Last, mock the EntityManager to return the mock of the repository
        $entityManager = $this
            ->getMockBuilder(ObjectManager::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $entityManager->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getRepository')
            ->will($this->returnValue($employeeRepository));

        $salaryCalculator = new SalaryCalculator($entityManager);
        $this->assertEquals(2100, $salaryCalculator->calculateTotalSalary(1));
    }
}
```

In this example, you are building the mocks from the inside out, first creating the employee which gets returned by the Repository, which itself gets returned by the EntityManager. This way, no real class is involved in testing.

Source :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html